# I have the following query whenever I run it, it gives me incorrect syntax near 'As'

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
CAST((Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14)*0.14 AS [Service Tax]
FROM APDEPADV
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
SELECT 
(CAST(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14)*0.14 AS [Service Tax]
FROM APDEPADV
```

You should be casting `Discount_Amount` first, *then* perform the other calculations:

1. Cast Discount_Amount as a numeric value
2. Next, divide the result by 1.14
3. Finally, multiply it all by 0.14

If you break your code down a little, you may understand what's going on:

1. `CAST` has the following syntax: `CAST(a AS b)`
2. Your code has: `CAST((Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14)`
3. Because you have the division *inside* the `CAST` function, then the whole expression `(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14` is treated as the value you want to cast (`a` in point 1 above).

This has a couple of consequences. First, `CAST(a AS b)` has now become `CAST(a)`, which doesn't make much sense (what are you casting it to?)

Secondly, it means that the expression `Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2)` is being processed separately to the `CAST` function. Something like `Discount_Amount/1.14` is a valid expression, but `(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14` on its own is not, which is why you're receiving the error.

By rearranging the parentheses, you should get closer to what you intend:

```
SELECT
(
    CAST(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))
    /1.14
)
* 0.14
AS [Service Tax]
FROM APDEPADV
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
    (CAST(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14)*0.14 AS [Service Tax]
    FROM APDEPADV
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of parentheses is wrong. Understand the expression and then re-write the parentheses accordingly.

```
SELECT
((Cast(Discount_Amount AS numeric(11,2))/1.14)*0.14 AS [Service Tax]
FROM APDEPADV
```